# Trying to set up a java project with cucumber framework

Tags: java, java-8, cucumber

I am trying to setup a java project using java 8

but getting errors:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactoryService has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:69)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactoryService has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1020)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:960)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:957)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:552)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.<init>(AbstractVerifier.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.<init>(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:44)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.<clinit>(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:46)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLSocketFactory.java:153)
    at io.restassured.config.SSLConfig.<init>(SSLConfig.java:184)
    at io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:420)
```

Updated to java 17 again fails since the project internally uses file compatible with java 8, don't want to change the entire project please guide?

Following dependencies used:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.0-RC2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need help in figuring out why I am getting this error want to use java 8 only

Comment: Then make sure your libraries are Java 8 compatible. Many are no longer, since we have Java 21 already.

Comment: which are not compatible? How to find out?

Comment: Well the stacktrace already tells you one library that isn't compatible (although looks like it's a pulled in dependency). The documentation / home page for libraries also tells about compatibility.

Comment: Can you share the home page?

Comment: Here's a homepage for you: https://duckduckgo.com/

Comment: @Anushka the second part of the stack trace originates from RestAssured. So that's probably the dependency that doesn't work with Java 8.